# How to make two HTML buttons active at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, tabs

I was following this tutorial to make clickable tabs https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp
Made horizontal and vertical ones. 
I would like to have both buttons active at the same time. For instance if any the horizontal buttons is active (number less than 6) than first vertical button (number 6) is active, and oppositely. If 6th is active than first horizontal button active too. I tried adding class like that but the active classes after weren't able to be removed:

```
tablinks[6].className = tablinks[6].className.replace("", " active");
```

How can i make this happen?

here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Main</title>
<style>
    /* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 4%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}



/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the bar content */
body {margin:0}
#bar {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 3cm;
}
.icon-bar {
    width: 40px;
}

div.icon-bar button {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 15px;
}
div.icon-bar button.active {
    background-color: steelblue !important;
    color: white;
}
i{
    width: 20px;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 25px;
}


</style>
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName, numero) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    if(numero <6){
        //no idea what to do here
    }

    console.log(document.getElementById("wiki").classList);
    console.log(tablinks);
    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'trends', 0);">Google Trends</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'youtube', 1);">YouTube</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'books_ah', 2);">OL Books(A&H)</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'books_all', 3);">OL Books All</button> 
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'wos_all', 4);">WoS(all)</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'wos_ah', 5);">WoS(A&H)</button>
    </div>

    <div id = "bar">
        <div class="icon-bar">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'wiki', 6);"><i class="fa fa-wikipedia-w"></i></button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'youtube_table', 7);"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'books_table', 8);"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'method', 9);"><i class="fa fa-calculator"></i></button>  
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'dataset', 10);"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'about', 11);"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div id="trends" class="tabcontent">
        <object data="./images/Trends.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: Trends.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="youtube" class="tabcontent">
        <object data="./images/Youtube.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: Youtube.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="books_ah" class="tabcontent">
        <object data="./images/OLbooks.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: OLbooks.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="books_all" class="tabcontent">
        <object data="./images/OLbooks_all.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: OLbooks_all.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="wos_ah" class="tabcontent">
        <object data="./images/Wos_AH.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: wos_ah.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="wos_all" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/Wos_all.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: wos_all.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="wiki" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/Trends.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: Trends.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="youtube_table" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/table2.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: table2.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="books_table" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/table3.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: table3.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="method" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/methodology.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: methodology.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="dataset" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/dataset.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: dataset.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <div id="about" class="tabcontent">
    <object data="./images/about.html" width="1200" height="900">Warning: about.html could not be included!</object>
    </div>

    <script>document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks')[0].click()</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi cheers for the comment, it becomes active for the first click, but after the second, another vertical button becomes active, and later third until all are highlighted. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to highlight the 1st horizontal button for all the active vertical ones and the 1st vertical button for all the active horizontal ones. If so, this should do the trick.

```
if(numero <6){
  tablinks[6].classList.add('active');
} else {
  tablinks[0].classList.add('active');
}
```